# Cannot pass ParentA<ChildA> instance to generic method(IParent<IChild>)

Tags: c#, interface

I wish to generalize `Util.Check` method for `ParentA` & `ParentB` classes. 
However, an error shows: cannot convert from ParentA to IParent.

```
public interface IChild {}
public interface IParent<TChild> where TChild : IChild
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    List<TChild> list { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : IChild { }
public class ChildB : IChild { }

public class ParentA : IParent<ChildA>
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<ChildA> list { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB : IParent<ChildB>
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<ChildB> list { get; set; }
}

public static class Util
{
    public static IParent<IChild> Check<IParent>(IParent<IChild> parent)
    {
        parent.message = "test";
        return parent;
    }
}

var parentA = new ParentA();
var parentB = new ParentB();
var resultA = Util.Check<ParentA>(parentA); // got an error here
var resultB = Util.Check<ParentB>(parentB); // got an error here
```

The error shows:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ParentA' to 'IParent<IChild>'
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ParentB' to 'IParent<IChild>'
```

Comment: See [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: See comment above)

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, even for sample code like this.

Comment: Interface member also couldn’t have access modifier

Comment: @BasilKosovan: It can in C# 8. It's not idiomatic to do so in a case like this, but the types shown here all compile - it's only the bottom two lines that don't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right - because a `ParentA` *isn't* an `IParent<IChild>`. Consider what would happen if this were allow. The code below would be fine:

```
// Invalid code: if the first line were valid, the rest would be unsafe.
IParent<IChild> parent = new ParentA();
List<IChild> list = parent.list;
IChild child = new ChildB();
list.Add(child);
```

That's just added a `ChildB` to an object which is actually a `List<ChildA>`, breaking type safety. But every line of that is okay *if* you can treat a `ParentA` as an `IParent<IChild>`.

Generic variance allows this *kind* of thing to be done in certain situations - but the rules make it safe to do so. In this case it *wouldn't* be safe to do so, so it's prohibited.

Comment: Thx @jon-skeet but, `IParent<IChild> parent = new ParentA();` got Error: CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ParentA' to 'IParent<IChild>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @ytk: Yes, that's the whole point. That *isn't* valid code, precisely because if the first line were valid, the rest would be unsafe. The aim of the answer is to explain to you why *your* code is invalid, via a simpler example. I've added a comment in the code snippet to clarify that.